# Define listeners in controller ExtJS

Tags: extjs, controller, listener

I have got the `tabpanel` - it's the `main` form (view).
In this `tabpanel` I define the different tabs - `xtype:'panel'`.

So, I have one `main`(controller) , `main` view and some tabs views.
The tab's views are referenced in `main` view.

I want to define listener of `activate` event of some child's `panel` in `main` controller.

How can I do that?

the `main` controller :

```
Ext.define('KP.controller.account.apartment.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: ['account.apartment.Main',
        'account.apartment.Requisites'
    ],

    models: ['account.apartment.Requisites'
    ],
    stores: ['account.apartment.Requisites'
    ],


    init: function () {

    }
});
```

The `main` view:

```
Ext.define('KP.view.account.apartment.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.ApartmentData',

    height: 566,
    width: 950,
    activeItem: 0,
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },
    autoShow: false,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {            
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'tabpanel',
                    activeTab: 0,
                    deferredRender: true, 

                    items: [                        

                        {
                            xtype: 'RequisitesApartment'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

The child `panel` RequisitesApartment (view):

```
Ext.define('KP.view.account.apartment.Requisites', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.RequisitesApartment',


    id: 'panel_accountrequisites',
    height: 350,
    width: 1124,
    autoScroll: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },


    listeners: {
        activate: function () {           
               ....load data....
               ...this listeners I want to push in 'main' controller...            
        }
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        var grid_store = Ext.create('KP.store.account.apartment.Requisites');

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    height: 260,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    store: grid_store,
                    id: 'r_gridFlatParams',
                    forceFit: true,


                    columns: [
                        ...some columns....
                    ],
                    viewConfig: {
                }
            }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register it directly as **[control](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control)** within the responsible controller

Here is a example with a working query. For sure you just will need the query, but I think it's a good example. The custom cfg property ident make it easy find each tab. As in the example below you will have specify a tabConfig within each panel and define the ident there.

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [{
        title: 'Foo',
        tabConfig: {
            ident: 'foo'
        },
    }, {
        title: 'Bar',
        tabConfig: {
            ident: 'bar',
            title: 'Custom Title',
            tooltip: 'A button tooltip'
        }
    }]
});

console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tabpanel tabbar tab[ident=foo]')[0]);
console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('tabpanel tabbar tab[ident=bar]')[0]);
```

Another way is to use css id's which can be queried like `'#my-name'` but I recommend to use a custom one as in the example above

Comment: @Oleg edit done. With this example you direct access to each tab

Comment: In 'main'(controller) I write :    this.control({
            'ApartmentData tabpanel tabbar tab[ident=foo]': {
                activate: function (grid) {
                    console.log('parampampam');
                }
            }
        }); - But it is not work(

Comment: @Oleg First; you should write widgets in lower case and only classnames in camelcase. Second; have you applied a tabConfig along with `xtype: 'RequisitesApartment'`? The Example above can be copied into one of the example code fields within the sencha API.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I should put this code in 'main'(controller):

```
 this.control({
        'ApartmentData tabpanel RequisitesApartment': {
            activate: function () {
                console.log('hello!');                
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem was in wrong selector , that I used.
The correct selector is :

```
 'ApartmentData tabpanel RequisitesApartment'
```

There 'ApartmentData'(define like a `alias: 'widget.ApartmentData'`) - is the 'window' xtype -the main form.
tabpanel  - panel with tabs in 'window', and 'apartServList'(define like `alias: 'widget.RequisitesApartment'`) - the some panel.

Thanks for [sra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701988)!

Comment: Well, `apartServList` can not be found in your example code. So it will be a bit hard to track for others why this is the correct answer. Me included. Maybe you could edit your question.

Comment: And please note that my example points you to the tab-button itself, not to the tab. As Far as I know the activate event  of the tab is not bubbled to the panel, isn't it?

Comment: I edited my answer, in the 'panel' xtype have  the  'activate' event .

Answer (score 0):

the correct thing to do is to pass a config object to the member function **control** into *controller* **init** function. From Sencha documentation : *The control function makes it easy to listen to events on your view classes and take some action with a handler function.*

A quick example straight from extjs docs:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

init: function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport > panel': {
            render: this.onPanelRendered
        }
    });
},

onPanelRendered: function() {
    console.log('The panel was rendered');
}
});
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: How we can add multiple listener for a store inside controller file? var ps = this.getMyStore();

ps.on({ 
 beforesync : this.beforesync,
 finishupdate : this.finishupdate,
 finishedWriting: this.finishedWriting,
    scope: this
    
});